# PHP ActionScript Error

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-2

I write PHP and ActionScript and connect them
but result error

Here is the ActionScript

```
var filepath:String;

if (_url.indexOf("http") != 0) filepath = "http://localhost/adaptasi/";
else filepath = "../scripts/";

var send_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var result_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

result_lv.onLoad = function(success:Boolean):Void {
   TextIsi1.text = result_lv;
}

send_lv.sendAndLoad(filepath + "morfologi.php", result_lv, "GET");
```

And here is the PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "adaptasi";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM materi";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

and the result is error:
Error SELECT * FROM materi & onLoad= type Function

Comment: I use ActionScript 2

Comment: You should know that your PHP script will always return that message because simply that's what you've tell it to do !

Comment: What are you trying to do in your PHP script ?

Comment: I don't know what to do akmozo, please let me know

Comment: I meant, why you need that PHP script ? For what you are using it ? It should return something to your SWF, what is it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96666/discussion-between-candra-herk-and-akmozo).

Comment: Bump, Still no answer

Comment: @CandraHerk but you have been told the answer. Your result is correct because that's what that php code does... look carefully at `$sql = `... now you tell it to `echo` (or show) a result that says that `"Error: "` plus whatever is `$sql` plus other stuff, can you see what is happening?

Comment: Try changing echo line to this `echo "From PHP result : " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;`... If this is not the problem please update your question with what you expect to happen from your shown code...

Comment: I try your advice but result the 'Unidentified'

Comment: Well on my computer when I edited your PHP to change the _echo_ line to  `echo "From PHP result : " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;` it shows in browser as saying **From PHP result : SELECT * FROM materi** so I don't know why for you the browser says "Unidentified"..?? Anyway from your other question it seems you are getting closer to a solution. I only know I tested your code and it worked fine for me. Just sayin.